# Discord.py unable to get certificate

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, discord.py

Do I have to install/generate/download new certificate inside my system or is it possible for me somehow to disable certificates inside the python? (`ubuntu 18, python 3.7, discord.py latest`)

```
[INFO]  [2019.03.05 - 22:58:02]   Initializing Discord...

SSL handshake failed on verifying the certificate
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0xf4a9f8ec>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=12 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build/Lib/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 625, in _on_handshake_complete
  File "./build/Lib/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
  File "./build/Lib/ssl.py", line 763, in do_handshake
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)

SSL error in data received
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0xf4a9f8ec>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport closing fd=12 read=idle write=<idle, bufsize=0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build/Lib/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 526, in data_received
  File "./build/Lib/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
  File "./build/Lib/ssl.py", line 763, in do_handshake
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)

[ERROR] [2019.03.05 - 22:58:02]   
2019.03.05 - 22:58:02:
  Top:  file: [sv_custom.py], method: init()
  Root: file: [connector.py], line 974, cause: in _create_direct_connection [File "./../source/aiohttp.whl/aiohttp/connector.py", line 927, in _wrap_create_connection]
  aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError:
  Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)')]
```

This is done from the python that is inside the game client. If I do the same from the system's python (3.6) - no errors, connection is fine. "They say" it could be because the game client does not see "root certificates" or something like that.

Update:
Found out how to check certificates.

```
(with ssl error)
Initializing Discord...
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None, capath=None, openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/usr/local/ssl/certs')


(this works fine)
igor@Linbox:~/Downloads$ python3.6 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())"
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None, capath='/usr/lib/ssl/certs', openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/usr/lib/ssl/certs')
```

Guess that is my problem that `capath` is empty.

Comment: SSL errors are a bit tricky. Often times there's a proxy in-between you and the site such as a VPN or transparent proxy put in by a network administrator. Also, if your system time is screwy, it can effect the certificate verification process. Can you visit discordapp.com:443 inside your browser? This isn't a straight answer, I apologize but I lack the reputation to leave a comment.

Comment: I understand your point but it is not about the proxy (my network is transparent, 443 port works). As I mentioned in the end: python3.6 directly from the system + discord = no errors. Game client + own python client (from libpython3.7m.so.1.0 - built with ssl support) + discord = this ssl connection error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unexpectedly the solution appeared quite simple:

`ssl.get_default_verify_paths()` for the python with the ssl error was pointing to: `openssl_capath='/usr/local/ssl/certs'` while the "native" python from the system showed `openssl_capath='/usr/lib/ssl/certs'`.

```
DefaultVerifyPaths(
  cafile=None,
  capath=None,
  openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE',
  openssl_cafile='/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem',
  openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR',
  openssl_capath='/usr/local/ssl/certs'
)
```

I've checked both locations:
`'/usr/local/'` - was empty (it had no `ssl/certs` folders)
`'/usr/lib/ssl/certs'` had a symlink to `'/etc/ssl/certs'`
So I made the same symlink:
inside `'/usr/local/'` added `'/ssl/'` + `ln -s '/etc/ssl/certs' certs`

Then I checked once again `ssl.get_default_verify_paths()`

```
DefaultVerifyPaths(
  cafile=None,
  capath='/usr/local/ssl/certs',  <-- not empty now
  openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE',
  openssl_cafile='/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem',
  openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR',
  openssl_capath='/usr/local/ssl/certs'
)
```

The problem disappeared. It is working now.

Comment: You are my hero! This is the only solution worked for me

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/423 if one goes to the python folder one's computer and runs the `Install Certificates.command` it works.

I tried this and DOES work. 
Hope this helps both you and my reputation of StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Igorz, I opened up the '/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem' file and added the certificates from the website I was trying to access. You can get the details on how to get those certificates from [here](https://medium.com/@menakajain/export-download-ssl-certificate-from-server-site-url-bcfc41ea46a2).