# Python Discord Bot Troubleshooting

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

So I am using Pycharm, installed the discord.py and asyncio libraries in project interpreter. And I basically followed this video on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-7zuNRjqhw&t=190s
I have also tried other approaches like using atom which didn't work because of the python 3.7 and asyncio error.

If anyone can tell me what's going on that would be great or any other way to make a python discord bot, I am open to ideas.

the code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("hello")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(str):
    await client.say("pong")

client.run("NTU3MjU2MTc5NTQyMTMwNzA5.D3FpXQ.QpSaso3vStRTet1m8CT8GYAJMvM")
```

and if I ran this code then it will return these error messages.

```
    /Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/bin/python /Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 601, in _create_direct_connection
    local_addr=self._local_addr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 809, in create_connection
    sock, protocol_factory, ssl, server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 835, in _create_connection_transport
    yield from waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 505, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 201, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:847)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 304, in connect
    yield from self._create_connection(req)
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 578, in _create_connection
    transport, proto = yield from self._create_direct_connection(req)
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 624, in _create_direct_connection
    (req.host, req.port, exc.strerror)) from exc
aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError: [Errno 1] Can not connect to discordapp.com:443 [[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:847)]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    client.run("NTU3MjU2MTc5NTQyMTMwNzA5.D3FpXQ.QpSaso3vStRTet1m8CT8GYAJMvM")
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 519, in run
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 473, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 490, in start
    yield from self.login(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 416, in login
    yield from getattr(self, '_login_' + str(n))(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 346, in _login_1
    data = yield from self.http.static_login(token, bot=is_bot)
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 258, in static_login
    data = yield from self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 137, in request
    r = yield from self.session.request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 555, in __iter__
    resp = yield from self._coro
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 198, in _request
    conn = yield from self._connector.connect(req)
  File "/Users/SoyMilkFrank/PycharmProjects/untitled13/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 314, in connect
    .format(key, exc.strerror)) from exc
aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError: [Errno 1] Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [Can not connect to discordapp.com:443 [[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:847)]]
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x10f6805c0>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. My bot that was working before is getting this same error now when I try to run it. My guess is that the discord servers are down because the part of the error `aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError: [Errno 1] Cannot connect to host discordapp.com` towards the bottom

Comment: do you think the other errors are built off that big one?

Comment: Well the main error is `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:847)` so I think maybe discord servers currently have an invalid SSL certificate and their network managers need to update it or something

Comment: so it should be working again soon? and it's not my software or hardware problems?

Comment: I would think so, unless my hardware suddenly experienced the same exact error as yours (that'd be epic!). Like I said I had a working bot script and now it gets the very same error as your much smaller script, so I think it's a discord problem and not a you problem

Comment: btw i can run a discord bot on java and it would have no problem logging in and it's done using the same computer

Comment: Hmmm. That's a pretty interesting piece to the puzzle...

Comment: i might have found the answer to the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012726/discord-py-unable-to-get-certificate

Comment: if you understand the solution can you explain it to me?

Comment: That didn't really help me since I'm on Windows. Have you gone to discordapp.com:443 in your web browser? I get "discordapp.com normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Google Chrome tried to connect to discordapp.com this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be discordapp.com, or a sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. You cannot visit discordapp.com right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later."

Comment: Although that doesn't explain why your Java bot works

Comment: i think i found the solution

Comment: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/423

Comment: the reason is python 3.6 is kinda of messed up with mac os and changing it to python 3.5.2 would solve the entire problem

Comment: That's interesting because I'm running 3.5 on Windows and getting the error. Maybe it's just blocked by a system admin or something, and I need to try again on a private network?

Comment: Did your problem get solved from switching to 3.5?

Comment: yes my problems are solved after i switched to python 3.5

Comment: You should post what you did to fix it then as the answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

First of all do you need:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
```

Just replace it with:

```
@client.command()
```

Next for the ping function:

```
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong!")
```

Hope this helps, if you need any extra help join the Discord API Discord server. Also make sure you have the latest version of discord.py using pip