# Discord.py Bot: SSL cetificate not found

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, traceback

I'm a French beginner developer. Recently I've been thinking about making a Discord Bot in Python. So I watched a few videos but no matter how much I copied what they were doing, I kept getting errors on the console. So I looked at a few French forums and finally came across this piece of code that worked for some people, but with me there was always an error.

Here is my code:

```
import discord
 
TOKEN = "<Token>"

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.content.startswith('$ command'):
            await message.channel.send("C'est une commande très bizarre ! :yum:")

client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Here is the error on the console:

```
2023-11-30 22:03:33 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1112, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1145, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 574, in _on_handshake_complete
    raise handshake_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 556, in _do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 979, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<Users>/Desktop/Discord/Bot.py", line 19, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 849, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 777, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 612, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 803, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 625, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 536, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 540, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 901, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1206, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 982, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)')]
```

If someone can help me please, or answer me in French if you are...  Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012726/discord-py-unable-to-get-certificate

Comment: Can you specify your operation system (Windows, Linux, Mac, ...) you are using. Because the solution to the SSL issue might be OS depnedent.

Comment: My Os for this project is MacOS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py unable to get certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012726/discord-py-unable-to-get-certificate)